# Create custom action for custom button

Tags: apex, opportunity

hy!
I have created new custom button named as "Readmit" on detail page of opportunity in lightning view.i want to make this functional, such as that when a user click on this button,a new opportunity should generate with "Opportunity Name","Phone" and "Mobile" of current opportunity.

please guide me how i can do this.

Comment: What kind of button have you created? Is it visualforce page button or Lightning Component button or Javascript or url?

Comment: Thanks for reply,
i have created visualforce page button, i don't know this is right or not, actually i am new to salesforce.
please have look image.
https://pasteboard.co/HCMdAHy.png

Comment: Is there a relationship between old opportunity and new opportunity? A lookup field? You can use standard quickactions with predefined fields.

Comment: No there is not relationship between old and new opportunity.

Comment: Yopu might have to look into lightning data services component,

Comment: @PranayJaiswal can explain more detail, about quickactions. how i can use them.

Comment: So quick actions are lightning way of custom javascript buttons/action. It opens a modal and you can insert your lightning component. So in our quickaction we would insert a lightning base component that will copy value from the Opportunity on whom the Quick Action button was pressed.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xZytdo9pSK4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Uzman I am sharing a sample code which you can use to achieve your functionality:-

Here is your VF page where I am calling the action from Controller which will create the new Opportunity:-

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity" extensions="CLONEController" action="{!cloneOpp}">
    <apex:slds />
    <apex:pageMessages />
</apex:page>
```

Now, In your apex:-

```
     public class CLONEController{
            private PageReference pr;
            public Opportunity oppy {get;set;}  

        public CLONEController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
                String oppId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Id');
                oppy =[ select Id,Name,StageName,Type,CloseDate,AccountId,Amount from opportunity where id = :oppId];
            }
    public PageReference cloneOpp()
        {
            Opportunity newOpp = oppy.clone(false, true, false, false);
            newOpp.AccountId = oppy.AccountId;
            newOpp.Name = oppy.Name;
            newOpp.StageName = 'Pre-Qualification'; 
            newOpp.Type = 'New Business';
            newOpp.CloseDate = Date.Today();
            try{
            insert newOpp;
            return new PageReference('/' + newOpp.Id + '/e' );    
            }
            catch (DMLException e)
            {
            ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR,'Failed to create clone'));
            return null;
            }
    }
}
```

Now make use of it as a button and use it on Your Opportunity Layout. It will work in both Classic and Lightning.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: thanks for code snippet,
can you further explain that where i have to write the apex tag related code and where have to write the class and methods.

Comment: You don't need to add anything further in vf page. What you all need is setting the default value in apex controller like I have done in cloneOpp() method. I have set the default value of Name, stage name,accountid,Type, Closedate. Like that you can set any field you want.

Comment: where does apex controller exist ?

Comment: I have given you two things in my snippet. The first one is a visualForce page and the second one is the apex controller of that page.

Comment: i am trying to create new apex class, but there is no link to create new apex class, please see the image.
https://pasteboard.co/HCMsI0h.png
how i can create new apex class ?

Comment: Go to developer console-->click on file-->click on new-->select apex class-->name it and click ok to create

Comment: Welcome :) @uzman